# how i can delete something from file?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, files

i want to delete something from each line of file for example :-

i have the following path in file :
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core/db/fs-type
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees/db/fs-type
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/merchantserver/db/fs-type

i want to do something to become 
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core/
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees/
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/merchantserver/

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Are these lines of data in a file, or a list of files, or what?  If you give a bit of context, it'll help get answers.

Comment: Do you want to delete a string or you want to perform a substitution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -ie 's/db\/fs-type//g' FILENAME
or cat FILENAME | sed -e 's/db\/fs-type//g'
```

howto: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: i try two command ... command cat FILENAME | sed -e 's/db\/fs-type//g'  work :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is simple substitution, and for that the use of a tool like sed with simple regular expression matching is the classical means of achieving your goal. A simple search turns up a ton of links, but here are two that should get you started on your way:

Generally using sed for string replacement in a file:
http://www.cs.hmc.edu/tech_docs/qref/sed.html

An example a little more specific to your situation:
http://www.computing.net/answers/unix/replace-a-complex-string-using-sed/5811.html

This is one of the most common sorts of problems to solve, and solutions are fairly ubiquitous in the Linux community.